# RxJava: how to unsubscribe a subject from an observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java3

Using RxJava3, given an `Observable` and a `Subject`, I can subscribe the Subject to the Observable:

```java
observable.subscribe(subject); // returns void, not a subscription
```

Later, my Subject is not interested anymore in the Observable, how to unsubscribe it from the Observable ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest option is to use an [overload of `subscribe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Action-) that returns a [`Disposable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/disposables/Disposable.html), and have each handler call the appropriate method on your `Subject`, like this:

```java
Disposable d = observable
    .subscribe(subject::onNext, subject::onError, subject::onComplete);

// Later
d.dispose();
```

You could also create a [`DisposableObserver`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/observers/DisposableObserver.html) that forwards all messages to the `Subject`, and use [`subscribeWith`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#subscribeWith-E-) instead of `subscribe`, though it's more verbose:

```java
Disposable d = observable
.subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
         @Override public void onStart() {
         }
         @Override public void onNext(Integer t) {
             subject.onNext(t);
         }
         @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
             subject.onError(t);
         }
         @Override public void onComplete() {
             subject.onComplete();
         }
     });
```

I'm not aware of any cleaner options, and [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4438) from the RxJava bug tracker seems to back that up, though it is targeted at RxJava2.